# Non-Silverlight application build: Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to run my team's website in Visual Studio 2015. When I try to debug it I get the following message:

> Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed.

Clicking OK (only option) on that shows another error:

> Unable to Attach to application 'chrome.exe' using 'pc-name'. Operation Aborted. Do you want to continue anyway?

Clicking yes repeats both error boxes, clicking no stops debugging.

The annoying part is that Silverlight is **not used anywhere** in this project or in the whole solution.

Why is this happening, and how can I get it to stop so I can debug this website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try see in the *website / properties / web / debuggers* section if "Silverlight" is checked

Comment: That was it, wow. I must have clicked it accidentally once. I didn't see this option when I was trying to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You may also have to uninstall "Microsoft Silverlight" form Add/Remove Programs (only uninstall that exact one). Then install the developer runtime (Silverlight_Developer.exe or Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe) from  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72eeedda-fd89-4ccb-85b2-7001ac5c6c47.